# Elementary row operations effect on determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have the matrix

$$
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  2  & 3 & 4\\
-1 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & -1 & 1 & 2\\
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I should be able to add multiples of any row to another row and not affect the determinant.

By adding $1$ times the first row to the second row, $-1$ times the first to the third, and $1$ times the first to the fourth, I should still have the same determinant.

This results in the matrix

$$
B = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  2  & 3 & 4\\
0 & 3 & 5 & 7\\
0 & -3 & -2 & -2\\
0 & 3 & 2 & 5\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However,

$$\det(A) = 27,\quad \det(B) = 87$$

What am I missing? I am expecting $\det(B) = 27$ since I am only adding multiples of the first row to the others.

Comment: By my calculation $\det(B)=27$, just as it should (assuming that your calculation of $\det(A)$ is correct). Concretely, $$\begin{align*}\det(B)&=(3)(-2)(5)+(5)(-2)(3)+(7)(-3)(2)-(7)(-2)(3)\\&\qquad-(5)(-3)(5)-(3)(-2)(2)\\&=-30-30+75+12=87-60=27\;.\end{align*}$$

Comment: How did you calculate those determinants to be 27 and 87? It's a rather unwieldy computation for 4×4 matrices (except by the trick of doing some row/column operations first to make it more tractable. The difference could easily be due to a sign error somewhere -- especially since two of the terms in the complete expansion of $\det B$ have absolute value equal to half of the error.

Comment: sorry to waste your time on this, thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you made a mistake in computing ${\rm det}(B).$ I tried Maple, and ${\rm det}(B) = 27$ as well.

Here is Wolfram|Alpha for both [${\rm det}(A)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Determinant%28%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B-1%2C++1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%2C+%5B1%2C+-1%2C+1%2C+2%5D%2C+%5B-1%2C+1%2C+-1%2C+1%5D+%5D%29) and [${\rm det}(B)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Determinant%28%5B%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+-3%2C+-2%2C+-2%5D%2C+%5B0%2C+3%2C+2%2C+5%5D+%5D%29).

Comment: You're right. I thought I was going crazy. I put a - sign in front of entry 4,2 and the determinant got thrown off a bit. Thanks for the help. I typed it over a good 5 times and made that mistake every time